# AppRTC: iOS to Android Call is not working

Tags: android, ios, swift, webrtc, apprtc

We are developing an app using AppRTC. Audio and Video call from iOS-iOS and Android-Android are working fine but whenever we try to call from android to iOS or iOS to android, nothing happens after the call is accepted.

We have tried using the same Video codec (H264) on both android and iOS but the issue still persists.

Any assistance in this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do to solve this issue:

1. See if you are using https://apprtc.appspot.com instead of https://appr.tc, you should use  https://appr.tc for latest AppRTC.
2. Make sure you use "H264 Baseline" or "H264 High" video codec on android side as iOS supports H264 codec only.
3. Keep the following class updated with AppRTC github code PeerConnectionClient.java on android
4. Use latest AppRTC code on both iOS and Android